# Menu Stuck in IE7, IE8 - suckerfish?

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla, navigation

Please check out http://www.netcoremodeling.com in Chrome/Firefox/IE9, and then check it out in IE8, IE7. You will find the menu is sticking on a hover and will not close on mouseout in IE7 or IE8.

This is an extremely outdated website and was once built in Joomla, but has since been pulled out in a static site in a very cluttered, minimal time. I have been looking all over for a quick fix for a few hours and nothing relevant is popping up, or working.

Looking at this, can anyone give me a hint as to what could be a quick-fix for this? Without having to rebuild the whole menu from scratch?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions after posting them and receiving answers, even if they're too localized. It undermines the effort others have put in to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Message : Object doesn't support this property or method
>   Line : 20
>   Character : 4
>   Code : 0
>   URI : http://www.netcoremodeling.com/ja_menus/ja_cssmenu/ja.cssmenu.js

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("ja-cssmenu").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; ++i) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            if(this.className.indexOf("sfhover") == -1)
                this.className+= "sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.timer = setTimeout(sfHoverOut.bind(this), 20); <-- this line
        }
    }
}
```

But in fact, the whole js file is sorta useless, so you could just remove it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/ja_menus/ja_cssmenu/ja.cssmenu.js"></script>
```